# Why URL rewrite with international chars in HTTP_REFERER give error in IE 8,9,10?

Tags: url, url-rewrite-module

I’m using IIS ARR with URL rewrite and it’s working great in all browsers except Internet Explorer 8,9,10.

When I move from one page with international chars to another I’m getting this error:

---

"502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server."
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

---

Now I found that if I set in “Server Variables” the “HTTP_REFERER” to empty everything is working good.

So now I try to “{UrlDecode:{HTTP_REFERER}}” but it’s changing everything in the referer string so I can’t work with that.

Can anyone help me with that? what can I set in the HTTP_REFERER so it will not give me the error and will not change the output of HTTP_REFERER.

Screenshot with the setting that working:
http://sfile.f-static.com/image/users/17914/ftp/my_files/NoamFolder/arr_url_rewrite_working.png?id=12837466

Screenshot with the setting that not working:
http://sfile.f-static.com/image/users/17914/ftp/my_files/NoamFolder/arr_url_rewrite_not_working.png?id=12837467

Thanks,
Noa